# sqoop: multiple export paths

Tags: mapreduce, hdfs, etl, sqoop

Is it possible to export files in multiple HDFS locations in a single sqoop command? I tried to specify multiple `--export-dir` in the command, but seems only one is effective.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have three files:

```
.../basedir/folder_1/file.txt
.../basedir/folder_2/file.txt
.../basedir/folder_3/file.txt
```

To export three files, use

```
--export-dir .../basedir/*/file.txt
```

To export files in folder_1, folder_2, use

```
--export-dir .../basedir/{folder_1,folder_2}/file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In oozie workflow and using sqoop action, you can specify multiple paths, where each path is coming from job.properties:

```
<arg>--export-dir</arg>
<arg>${rootPath}/{${folder1},${folder2},${folder3}}</arg>
```

*Pay attention to curly brackets.*